# Is there a custom parsing service provider like an inverse IFormatProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parsing

I have several TextBoxes, which display angular values. I format these using different custom implementations of [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx), for example: The value `1.5707963267949` can be displayed as `1.5707963267949`, `0.5π` or `90°`. The TextBoxes are one-way-databound and I perform the formatting by handling the `Format` event of the Binding:

```
void bindingToMyTextBox_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // angleValueFormat is one of a few a custom implementations of 
    // IFormatProvider performing the actual formatting work.
    e.Value = String.Format(this.angleValueFormat, "{0:0.###}", (double)e.Value);
}
```

I want to allow the user to input values in the same format as they are displayed in. So I need to parse `TextBox.Text` to obtain the original value `1.5707963267949`. Is there any `"IParserProvider"` interface providing parsing services, like `IFormatProvider` in the opposite direction? Or would you suggest a different approach?

From what I understand, i can't use my IFormatProviders in the [Convert.ToDouble Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9s9ak971.aspx) because, to determine in which format the number to parse is, it uses only the [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx)-Object returned by the `IFormatProvider.GetFormat()`, which I obviously can't use to specify the necessary info.

Thank you!

richn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. I think mostly because in general it's not possible to automatically deduce a parser from a formatter (which is, iirc, internally implemented by a method `ICustomFormatter.Format`).

I would suggest to define your own interface

```
public interface IAngleParser {
    double ParseAngle(string);
}
```

and implement it in your classes for the `angleValueFormat` mamber. You'll probably have to use some regexes or so to do that.

Then you can use

```
void bindingToMyTextBox_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e) {
    e.Value = ((IAngleParser)this.angleValueFormat).ParseAngle(e.Value);
}
```

and bind this to your binding's `Parse` event.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your original values in some sort of container / dictionary. When you set it to the text box you format it, then when you want the original value you pull from the dictionary again.

```
e.Value = String.Format(this.angleValueFormat, "{0:0.###}", MyValues["ValueName"];
```

Comment: It's not necessarily the same value. I want to deal with user input in the formats I defined. Updated my question to reflect that.